# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'admin' (T_STRING) in

Tags: wordpress, plugins, syntax

i used this code in my plugin for showing database table on front end.

```
 $content .='<form method="post" action="<?php echo
```

admin_url('admin.php?page=Branches_table')
; ?>">';
But it showing error like that unexpected admin .
Anyone can solve it. plz

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$content .= '<form method="post" action="'. admin_url('admin.php?page=Branches_table') .'">';
```